# jQuery not executing in my newbie application

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to learn jQuery and I usually prefer 'learning-by-doing' so I am trying to create a simple rss reader by following this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-an-rss-reader-with-jquery-mobile-2/

I know I haven't missed any step that they said because I was able to appreciate and understand each line of code in the tutorial.

however, the part that requires jQuery to be in action never works.

first, I applied the following attributes in the basic structure but saw no difference

```
data-role="header"
data-role="content"
data-role="footer
```

I decided to move on and successfully completed the HTML parts.
now I came back to applying the following attributes

```
  data-role="listview" and

  data-role="list-divider", which can be applied to the <li> element.
```

still nothing changed.

now, I did what I wanted to do last: downloaded the source file and ran their final app yet I saw only the html stuff.

I would like to know whether there should be any configuration needed on my pc or whether am missing something. at least if i was typing out their codes wrongly their own final source code should work I guess.

ps. I also referenced the latest jquery mobile style sheet with no success.

Comment: pc settings = no. Lesson number 2 will need to be how to use a browser console to a) check for script errors and b) make sure path to scripts is correct and they are loading in page

Comment: @charlietfl the paths to the scripts was one of my early suspicions but have checked and rechecked it its correct. i checked developer console and it shows blank. i wanted to attache a screenshot to your comment but it seems that option is not available for comments

Comment: source on github is a lot of php files...for php you do need to run localhost server.... html files you don't. Not sure what your situation is. Post image in question

Answer (score 0):

Try opening up the browser debugger by hitting F12 and and looking for errors in there, then searching for those errors:

[image: Browser Debugging]

You need help finding the error/problem in your code. There is a great detailed guide at [FixingThesejQuery](http://fixingthesejquery.com/#slide1) that will take you step by step through the process. Check it out, certain to enjoy!